# Scala: how to get the mean and variance and covariance of a matrix?

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, matrix, variance

I am new to scala and I desperately need some guidance on the following problem:

I have a dataframe like the one below (some elements may be NULL)

```
val dfDouble = Seq(
  (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 3.0),
  (1.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0),
  (1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 1.0),
  (1.0, 4.0, 0.0, 2.0)).toDF("m1", "m2", "m3", "m4")

dfDouble.show
+---+---+---+---+
| m1| m2| m3| m4|
+---+---+---+---+
|1.0|1.0|1.0|3.0|
|1.0|2.0|0.0|0.0|
|1.0|3.0|1.0|1.0|
|1.0|4.0|0.0|2.0|
+---+---+---+---+
```

I need to get the following statistics out of this dataframe:

1. a vector that contains the mean of each column (some elements might be NULL and I want to calculate the mean using only the non-NULL elements); I would also like to refer to each element of the vector by name for example, vec_mean["m1_mean"] would return the first element

```
vec_mean: Vector(m1_mean, m2_mean, m3_mean, m4_mean)
```

2. a variance-covariance matrix that is (4 x 4), where the diagonals are `var(m1), var(m2),...,` and the off-diagonals are `cov(m1,m2), cov(m1,m3) ...` Here, I would also like to only use the non-NULL elements in the variance-covariance calculation
3. A vector that contains the number of non-null for each column

```
vec_n: Vector(m1_n, m2_n, m3_n, m4_n)
```

4. A vector that contains the standard deviation of each column

```
vec_stdev: Vector(m1_stde, m2_stde, m3_stde, m4_stde)
```

In R I would convert everything to a matrix and then the rest is easy. But in scala, I'm unfamiliar with matrices and there are apparently multiple types of matrices, which are confusing (DenseMatrix, IndexedMatrix, etc.)

Edited: apparently it makes a difference if the content of the dataframe is Double or Int. Revised the elements to be double

Used the following command per suggested answer and it worked!

```
val rdd = dfDouble0.rdd.map { 
  case a: Row => (0 until a.length).foldRight(Array[Double]())((b, acc) => 
  { val k = a.getAs[Double](b) 
    if(k == null) 
       acc.+:(0.0) 
    else acc.+:(k)}).map(_.toDouble) 
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo can work with Spark RowMatrix. It has these kind of operations like computing the co-variance matrix using each row as an observation, mean, varianze, etc... The only thing that you have to know is how to build it from a Dataframe.

It turns out that a Dataframe in Spark contains a schema that represents the type of information that can be stored in it, and it is not only floating point numbers arrays. So the first thing is to transform this DF to a RDD of vectors(dense vector in this case).

Having this DF:

```
  val df = Seq(
    (1, 1, 1, 3),
    (1, 2, 0, 0),
    (1, 3, 1, 1),
    (1, 4, 0, 2),
    (1, 5, 0, 1),
    (2, 1, 1, 3),
    (2, 2, 1, 1),
    (2, 3, 0, 0)).toDF("m1", "m2", "m3", "m4")
```

Convert it to a RDD Row[DenseVector] representation. There must be dozens of ways of doing this. One could be:

```
val rdd = df.rdd.map {
  case a: Row =>
    (0 until a.length).foldRight(Array[Int]())((b, acc) => {
      val k = a.getAs[Int](b)
      if(k == null) acc.+:(0) else acc.+:(k)
    }).map(_.toDouble)
}
```

As you can see in your IDE, the inferred type is **RDD[Array[Float]**. Now convert this to a **RDD[DenseVector]**. As simple as doing:

```
val rowsRdd = rdd.map(Vectors.dense(_))
```

And now you can build your Matrix:

```
val mat: RowMatrix = new RowMatrix(rowsRdd)
```

Once you have the matrix, you can easily compute the different metrix per column:

```
println("Mean: " + mat.computeColumnSummaryStatistics().mean)
println("Variance: " + mat.computeColumnSummaryStatistics().variance)
```

It gives:

```
Mean: [1.375,2.625,0.5,1.375]

Variance: 
[0.26785714285714285,1.9821428571428572,0.2857142857142857,1.4107142857142858]
```

you can read more info about the capabilities of Spark and these distributed types in the doc: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-data-types.html#data-types-rdd-based-api

You can also compute the Covariance matrix, doing the SVD, etc...

Comment: Matinez, when I ran `mat.computeColumnSummaryStatistics().mean`, I actually got a `java.lang.ClassCastException` if the entries to `df` is `double` instead of `integer`. Do you know why this might have happened?

Comment: you have to change the getAs[Int] to getAs[Double]

Comment: I tried the following command 

`
val rdd = dfDouble0.rdd.map {
  case a: Row =>
    (0 until a.length).foldRight(Array[Int]())((b, acc) => {
      val k = a.getAs[Double](b)
      if(k == null) acc.+:(0) else acc.+:(k)
    }).map(_.toDouble)
} 
`

but got the following error 

``
<console>:76: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Array[AnyVal]
 required: Array[Double]
Note: AnyVal >: Double, but class Array is invariant in type T.
You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ >: Double`. (SLS 3.2.10)
             if(k == null) acc.+:(0) else acc.+:(k)
``

Comment: Update the question with your problem. It will be much more readable

Comment: Note that with foldRight you create an array of int. If you change the the internal representation, the getAs[Double] tells the compiler that you collects doubles, but the array that you tell the compiler that is going to be created is of integers, so change the foldRight(Array[Int]()) to foldRight(Array[Double]())

Comment: I tried that as well, and still got an error, albeit a different error. Updated the question to reflect that error.

Comment: Instead of 0 put 0.0. Otherwise the compiler infers an int

Comment: Welcome, that is what we are here for