# How to calculate a correlation matrix in Spark using scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

In python `pandas` , when I have a `dataframe` df like this

| c1 | c2 | c3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.1 | 0.3 | 0.5 |
| 0.2 | 0.4 | 0.6 |

I can use `df.corr()` to calculate a correlation matrix .

How do I do that in spark with scala ?

I have read the official document , The data struct isn't like above . I don't know how to transfer it .

Update one:

```
val df = Seq(
    (0.1, 0.3, 0.5,0.6,0.8,0.1, 0.3, 0.5,0.6,0.8),
    (0.2, 0.4, 0.6,0.7,0.7,0.2, 0.4, 0.6,0.7,0.7),
).toDF("c1", "c2", "c3","c4","c5","c6", "c7", "c8","c9","c10")

val assembler = new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(Array("c1", "c2", "c3","c4","c5","c6", "c7", "c8","c9","c10")).setOutputCol("vectors")
```

How to show the whole result when the number of column is 10 ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the correlation matrix of a pyspark data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52214404/how-to-get-the-correlation-matrix-of-a-pyspark-data-frame)

Comment: No . It uses ```pyspark```  while I want a ```scala spark``` answer .

Comment: Check this out for a scala solution: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-statistics.html

Comment: Take a look to https://stackoverflow.com/a/70411405/6802156. Once you build the RowMatrix from the DF it´s immediate

Comment: I have read the document , its dataframe's struct isn't same as mine ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve your problem with the following code. It will apply the Pearson correlation which is also standard for the Pandas function.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vectors
import org.apache.spark.ml.stat.Correlation

val df = Seq(
    (0.1, 0.3, 0.5),
    (0.2, 0.4, 0.6),
).toDF("c1", "c2", "c3")

val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
  .setInputCols(Array("c1", "c2", "c3"))
  .setOutputCol("vectors")

val transformed = assembler.transform(df)

val corr = Correlation.corr(transformed, "vectors").head

println(s"Pearson correlation matrix:\n $corr")
```

Comment: It works ! Thanks ! By the way , ```println``` shows ```...``` . How to solve it ?

Comment: That sounds strange. The syntax looks right to me. What environment are you working on? Could it be that the three dots are hiding the output?

Comment: Yes , it is . I don't know how to show all the output in console ......

Comment: If you give some more details about the tools you are working with (Databricks?, Jupyter?, specific IDE?), I can maybe point you to the right direction :)

Comment: Thanks ~ It's ```scala spark shell```

Comment: Unfortunately I can not reproduce this in scala spark shell, my `println` in the shell works correctly. The most efficient thing would probably be to open a new question for this issue.

Comment: I update the question and add a case to reproduce it ~